# Can I use Next 10 with React 16?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, compatibility

The Next.js 10 Upgrade Guide has a section titled **React 16 to 17**.

However, it does not say if Next 10 is compatible with React 16 or not.

`package.json` has React 17 in the dependencies list:

```
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
```

Does it mean Next 10 is incompatible with React 16?

My particular case is that I must use a UI library that is not compatible with React 17 and only works with React 16. In the same time, I'd like to leverage some features of the latest Next. What are my options?

Comment: You can safely use Next.js 10 with React 16. There shouldn't be any issues with that.

Comment: So if I install react 16 while Next dependencies list react 17, which react will be used by Next? Probably it's more a node/npm question if asked this way.

Comment: React is a peer dependency in Next.js. Next will use the version you have installed in your project.

Comment: Is not peer dependency there to specify what React versions are accepted as dependencies of the host package?

Comment: Yes, and Next.js accepts both React 16 and 17. From its package.json: `"react": ^16.6.0 || ^17`

Comment: @juliomalves where do you see it? Version 10.1.2 package.json at https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v10.1.2/package.json says: `"react": "17.0.1"`

Comment: From Next.js `package.json`: https://www.github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/packages/next/package.json. Check the `peerDependencies`.

Comment: Okay thanks. Why is it that file and not the top-level `package.json`?

Comment: Next.js is a monorepo, the actual `next` module lives under `packages`. That's just how monorepos are structured.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Next.js v10 with either React 16 or 17.

React is a peer dependency in Next.js (check the `peerDependencies` in its [`package.json`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/package.json) to see the supported versions). Next will use the version you have installed in your project.